# Using complex variables to evaluate real trig integral

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

$$\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\cos(2\theta)}{1-2a\cos(\theta)+a^2}d\theta, -1< a < 1$$

I did the substitution $z = e^{i\theta}$ and then got $\cos(2\theta) = 1/2(z^2+1/z^2)$, so

$$\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\cos(2\theta)}{1-2a\cos(\theta)+a^2}d\theta = \frac{1}{i}\int_{|z|=1}\frac{1/2(z^2+1/z^2)}{1-az-a/z+a^2}dz.$$

Did I make a mistake here? Because I'm having an extremely difficult time simplifying this and using the residue theorem. I end up with some really terrible poles, and I end up having to use the binomial theorem to calculate the residues.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{z^2+z^{-2}}{(a-z)(a-z^{-1})}=\frac{z^4+1}{z(a-z)(az-1)}$$

Should be pretty easy to compute the residues at $z=0$ and $z=a$. (Just delete the corresponding factor from the denominator and plug in the value to compute the residues.)

Comment: Yes, didn't see it factored like that. Thanks.

Comment: I'm still having trouble because evaluating $\frac{z^4+1}{(a-z)(az-1)}$ at $z = 0$ gives $-1/a$ and the other residue is $\frac{a^4+1}{a^3-a}.$ But this doesn't make sense for $a = 0,$ nor does it lead to the correct expression for the integral.

Comment: @Jonathan If $a=0$ the integrand is ___ so the integral is ___?